# CordovaActivity cannot be resolved to a type in Phonegap 3.4

Tags: android, cordova

Hi I am working on `PhoneGap` through a command line interface.

I am able to create a project, and run an android emulator from the command prompt in Windows 7.

Since I imported and copied the project into my workspace in eclipse, it is showing some errors in the main class which extends `CordovaActivity`.

The error is:

```
"CordovaActivity cannot be resolved to a type".
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 12):

For those who don't want to use it from command line just add an external library cordova-android project to resolve this issue.

Follow these steps:

1- Download Cordova android zip from here https://github.com/apache/cordova-android.

2- Extract zip anywhere on your PC. Go inside framework folder.

3- Import this extracted zip folder/framework in your eclipse as an existing project which will result in Cordova project(library) in your workspace.

4- Now right click on your app project -> Properties -> Android. In the Library section choose 'Add' and select Cordova project(library).

5- Finally add import org.apache.cordova; to use extend CordovaActivity.

Comment: @Vaishali - glad that it worked for you .. :) Feel free to update the answer if you find anything else (any new step) is required as I posted this answer long time back.

Answer (score 8):

click the project and select Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source and Add Folder to include the CordovaLib\src folder.

(or)

if you have appname-CordovaLib as an existing project; You can add it to the sourcepath.

Comment: For me too on mac! Life saver! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get rid of the error by cleaning the project:

From the menu: Project > Clean...

Mac OS X 10.10, Eclipse Luna, and phonegap 3.6.0-0.21.18

Answer (score 0):

Add `cordova` jar in your project and then in your `Activity` which extends `CordovaActivity`
add this line to import the `cordova` classes

```
import org.apache.cordova.*;
```

Comment: yeah I added it already. In fact, I created this project using command line interface.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by this way.

1. Download cordova-android-master
2. Extract and goto framework directory
3. Open command prompt and run "ant jar" command
4. Again go to framework directory and
5. copy cordova-4.1.0-dev.jar file
6. Add this jar file into build path of the cordova project into eclipse.

This resolved all errors for me.