# Apache Cordova CordovaActivity cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, cordova, ubuntu-13.10

I have a similar problem to this:

[CordovaActivity cannot be resolved to a type in Phonegap 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23806667/cordovaactivity-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-in-phonegap-3-4).

Means, in the main class, `CordovaActivity` cannot be resolved to a type.

However, I downloaded Cordova Android Zip from here (as explained in the comments): 
https://github.com/apache/cordova-android.

And included `cordova-2.2.0.jar` from `./lib/android` to my build path.

The line:

```
import org.apache.cordova
```

works fine now, but still, it does not find any class called `CordovaActivity` for extension.

Which I prove by:

```
grep -r "CordovaActivity" *
```

on the unpacked `cordova-2.2.0.jar` folder.

What is wrong here?

[image]

---

besides that, there seems to be a package problem:
the main java file is located in `./src/com/testapp/test2`, in line 20 it says after I call `cordova -d build`:

```
package com.testapp.test;
```

with a red underline, that only disappears after I add `src.` before `com.testsapp.test2`. However, that gets crushed with every time I call `cordova -d build`. If I correct the path in the config.xml from

```
<widget id="com.testapp.test2" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

to

```
<widget id="src.com.testapp.test2" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

I will have a new package in my package explorer: `src.src.com.testapp.test2`, having the same problem.

That seems really weird.

Comment: Tried clean & build?

Comment: Project: clean leads to the console output: [2014-08-13 13:32:39 - test2] /test2/gen already exists but is not a source folder. Convert to a source folder or rename it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this one in the web. It helped me:
http://red-folder.blogspot.de/2014/01/cordova-330-cordovalib-and-eclipse.html

Answer (score 4):

So you are using Eclipse or Android Studio to build?

Anyway, you should add the Cordova module found in `platforms/android/CordivaLib` as a dependency to your project.

The way to do it for Eclipse is here >> http://red-folder.blogspot.de/2014/01/cordova-330-cordovalib-and-eclipse.html.

And the way to do it in Android Studio is here >> https://stackoverflow.com/a/19188384/1371913